# write equations into a 2 column table with left column showing the left side of the equation and right column showing the right side of the equation

Tags: tables, equations, formatting

I am writing a 2 column paper and I would like to organize my formulas into a table with 2 columns with the cells of the left column containing the left side of the equation and the cells in the right column containing the right side of the equation.

I would like to achieve this with the right side of each equation inside each of the cells of the right columns.

[image]

Here is what my equations currently look like:

[image]

Here is the source code I am using:

```
    \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}


% DOI
\acmDOI{xx.xxx/xxx_x}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-8104-8/21/03}

%Conference
\acmConference[SAC'21]{ACM SAC Conference}{March 22-March 26, 2021}{Gwangju, South Korea}
\acmYear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\acmArticle{4}
\acmPrice{15.00}


\pagestyle{plain}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
\begin{document}

\title{test}

\author{Anonymous Author(s)}





\begin{abstract}
abstract

\end{abstract}




\maketitle




\begin{gather*}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}
=\vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} 
  \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}} \\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
\vn{Low}&\vn{Combination} \\
&=\bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} \And \bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}} 
  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}})\bigr)\bigr) \\
&\quad \Or\bigl( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
\vn{Medium}&\vn{Combination}\\
&=\bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{M}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
&\quad \Or \bigl(( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} ) 
 \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}}\bigr)\bigr)\\[1ex]
\vn{High}&\vn{Combination}\\
&=\bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{H}} \Or\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
&\quad\Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}) \bigr)\bigr)
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

For this you not need a table, Just use `align*` math environment defined in the `amsmath`package:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
%\usepackage{booktabs, hhline, multirow} % For formal tables
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}
    & = \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}} \\[1ex]
%
\vn{Low}\vn{Combination} 
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} \And \bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}
        \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}})\bigr)\bigr) \\
    &\quad \Or\bigl( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
%
\vn{Medium}\vn{Combination}
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{M}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    &\quad \Or \bigl(( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} ) \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}}\bigr)\bigr)\\[1ex]
%
\vn{High}\vn{Combination}
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{H}} \Or\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    &\quad\Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}) \bigr)\bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
In two column document you equation in form as is, is to wide that can be fit in one column, You need to reorganize it for example as follows:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}
    & = \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}} \\[1ex]
%
\vn{Low}\vn{Combination} 
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} \And \bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}\\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}})\bigr)\bigr) \\
    &\quad \Or\bigl( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
%
\vn{Medium}\vn{Combination}
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{M}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    &\quad \Or \bigl(( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} ) \\
    &\quad\And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}}\bigr)\bigr)\\[1ex]
%
\vn{High}\vn{Combination}
    & = \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{H}} \\
    &\quad \Or\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    &\quad\Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    &\quad \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}) \bigr)\bigr)
\end{aligned}
\]
```

[image]

Edit (2):
After your editing of question, the desired presentation of your equation can be as:

[image]

```
\[
\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\text{combination}
    &  \text{definition}    \\
\hline
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}
    & \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}} \\[1ex]
\hline
\vn{Low}\vn{Combination} 
    & \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} \And \bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}\\
    & \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}})\bigr)\bigr) \\
    & \Or\bigl( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
\hline
\vn{Medium}\vn{Combination}
    & \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{M}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    & \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    & \Or \bigl(( \vn{Callers}^{\vn{N}} \Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{L}} ) \\
    &\quad\And \vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}}\bigr)\bigr)\\[1ex]
\hline
\vn{High}\vn{Combination}
    & \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{H}} \\
    & \Or\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    & \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}\bigr) \bigr) \\
    & \Or \bigl(\vn{Callers}^{\vn{H}}\And\bigl(\vn{Callees}^{\vn{M}} \\
    & \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{L}}  \Or \vn{Callees}^{\vn{N}}) \bigr)\bigr) \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]
```

Note, your MWE still produce one column document (not two column as you mentioned in comment). Please, clarify this par of your question too.

Comment: this overflows to the right column, I am writing a 2 column paper and I need the formulas to not overflow to the right . Also, I would like a real table with lines drawn and cells appearing with solid lines

Comment: @user3406764, sorry, from your MWE follows, that you have one column article. Of course, in two column version your equations in desired form are to wide. Please edit your question and make it more clear, i.e. correct your MWE accordingly (that it will generate two column document).

Comment: @user3406764, see edited answer. Anyway, please rewrite your MWE so, that it will generate two column document.